# AspectJ load time weaving not working for Spring beans

Tags: spring, aspectj, load-time-weaving

I am facing the same issue as:

[AspectJ load time weaving not working on Spring beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342526/aspectj-load-time-weaving-not-working-on-spring-beans)

The solution of returning 'Object' is working, but I don't know the reason.

I have gone through:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch08s08.html#aop-aj-ltw

but still no clue.

Comment: Please post some actual code/configuration to help you. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask questions.

Comment: thought that adding same content would not add anything. And don't know how people can respond on older (yours) question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AspectJ load time weaving not working on Spring beans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342526/aspectj-load-time-weaving-not-working-on-spring-beans)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented on that other thread.

The load-time weaver, as the name suggest, will only operate on the loading of classes. Now when a class is already loaded it cannot be processed anymore.

When the return type is the concrete class it will result in eagerly loading that class, it will be loaded before the load time weaver is registered and can do it stuff.

When the return type is `Object` the loading of the class is deferred until the class is actually needed and in general this will be after the load time weaver has been registered so it can do its work.

You can simply verify this behavior by adding `-verbose:class` as parameters when you run the program (like you would add properties). You then get an extensive list of classes when they get loaded.

Comment: got it. So why not use lazy-init=true?

Comment: Since I am using aspect for profiling. Can't we use compile time weaving? Don't know it will work for private methods or not.

Comment: @M.Deinum: I don't have much knowledge of spring, but is returning 'Object' only way to solve this problem?

Comment: @SIGSTP it has nothing to do with Spring but with class loading rules of the JVM.

Comment: @Azazle you can always use compile time weaving.